# Connecting AWS AD to Azure AD

Tags: microsoft-office-365, entra-id, aws-directory-service

We are looking in starting to use AD in our office, the setup would be:

- On premise AD server for work stations
- Azure AD to support Office 365
- AWS AD to support AD on our servers

Connecting on premise to Azure is fine, but is there a way to connect the Azure AD to the Amazon AD? The Azure needs to be the master AD where all users are managed.

Is such thing possible?

Comment: Why wouldn't you just use one or the other? Why do you want to use both?

Comment: Then I would have to manage users in 2 places.

Comment: I'm asking you why you want to use both.

Comment: You can't use either AD to connect anything outside their network to it. I can't hook up a Azure AD to AWS or vice versa.

Comment: I don't think we're on the same page. You state in your question that your setup includes on premises AD, Azure AD and AWS AD. I then asked you why you want to use all 3 in your set up and you replied that you can't use them. I'm confused as to what it is you're doing and what you're asking.

Comment: My question is, how do I make them all communicate with eachother so I don't need to manage users in 3 places.

Comment: @joeqwerty managed to derail this question without adding any value.

Comment: Troll much, @Fo?

Comment: You not understanding the question doesn’t make it invalid

Comment: I understood the question perfectly fine. I was questioning the use case. And your comments have added no value to a question that's 3 years old.

Comment: Thanks for giving me some hope by kicking this @Fo. Still looking for the answer lol.

Comment: Check this @YesMan85 : https://www.slideshare.net/AmazonWebServices/how-to-integrate-aws-directory-service-with-office365-aws-online-tech-talks , though it doesn't have Azure AD as the master, it does help demystify

Comment: Not that you've been waiting three years for an answer, but if you found one, those of us who find this question would love to see an accepted answer even if it's your own

Answer (score 1):

Are you using AzureAD or just hosting a domain controller in azure?

If its a normal Domain controller then you can just use the AWS domain connector to link them all together, having said that I think best practise would be to have your on premise AD as primary and then use LDAP/Connectors to export changes to Azure and AWS.

Comment: Maybe that's a better way to go yes, use the on-premise one as the master. I'm using Azure Active Directory. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/active-directory/